# Algorithm to give shortest expression for one number in terms of another number

Tags: python, algorithm, math, tree

Heads up: apologies for my poor style, inefficient code, and general stupidity. I'm doing this purely out of interest. I have no delusions that I will become a professional programmer.

How would solve this problem (assuming it can be solved). To be clear you want to take in an int x and an int y and return some expression in terms of y that equals x. For example if I passed in 9 and 2 one of the shortest solutions (I'm pretty sure) would be ((2+2)x2)+(2/2) with 4 total operators. You can assume positive integers because that's what I'm doing for the most part.

I have found a fastish partial solution that returns a solution for whatever numbers, but usually not the smallest one. Here it is coded in python:

```
def re_express(n, a, expression):
if n==0:
    print(expression)
else:
    if a**a < n:
        n -= a**a
        expression += "+" + str(a) + "^" +str(a)
        re_express(n, a, expression)
    elif a*a < n:
        n -= a*a
        expression += "+" + str(a) + "*" + str(a)
        re_express(n, a, expression)
    elif a < n:
        n -= a
        expression += "+" + str(a)
        re_express(n, a, expression)
    else:
        n -= 1
        expression += "+" + str(a) + "/" + str(a)
        re_express(n, a, expression)
```

I have also think I have one that returns a pretty small solution, but it is not guaranteed to be the smallest solution. I hand simulated it and it got the 2 and 9 example correct, whereas my first algorithm produced a 5 operator solution: 2^2+2^2+2/2. But it gets slow quickly for large n's. I wrote it down in pseudocode.

```
function re_express(n, a, children, root, solutions):

input: n, number to build 
       a, number to build with
       children, an empty array
       root, a node
       solutions, an empty dictionary

if not root:
    root.value = a 

if the number of layers in the tree is greater than the size of the shortest solution, return the shortest solution

run through each mathematical operator and create a child node of root as long as the child will have a unique value

each child.value = operator(root, a)

for each child: child.parent = root

for each child: child.operator = operator as a string

loop through all children and check to see what number you need to produce n with each operator, if that number is in the list of children

when you find something like that then you have paths back up the tree, use the following loop for both children (obviously a child with only i 

i = 0
while child != root:
    expression += “(“ + str(a) + child.operator
    child = child.parent
expression += str(a)
for in range(i):
    expression += “)”

then you combine the expressions and you have one possible solution to add up to n and you have one possible answer

store the solution in solutions with the key as the number of operators used and the value as the expression in string form

re_express(n, a, children, root, solutions)
```

As you can tell the big-O for that algorithm is garbage and it doesn't even give a guaranteed solution, so there must be a better way.

Answer (score 1):

We can use a variation of Dijkstra's algorithm to find the result. However, we don't really have a graph. If we consider numbers as nodes of the graph, then edges would start at a pair of nodes and an operation and end at another number. But this is just a detail that does not prevent Dijkstra's idea.

The idea is the following: We start with `y` and explore more and more numbers that we can express using a set of pre-defined operations. For every number, we store how many operations we need to express it. If we find a number that we have already seen (but the previous expression takes more operations), we update the number's attributes (this is the path length in Dijktra's terms).

Let's do the example `x = 9, y = 2`.

Initially, we can represent `2` with zero operations. So, we put that in our number list:

```
2: 0 operations
```

From this list, we now need to find the number with the least number of operations. This is essential because it guarantees that we never need to visit this number again. So we take `2`. We fix it and explore new numbers that we can express using `2` and all other fixed numbers. Right now, we only have 2, so we can express (using `+ - * /`):

```
2: 0 operations, fixed
0: 1 operation (2 - 2)
1: 1 operation (2 / 2)
4: 1 operation (2 + 2 or 2 * 2)
```

On we go. Take the next number with the least number of operations (does not matter which one). I'll take `0`. We can't really express new numbers with zero, so:

```
2: 0 operations, fixed
0: 1 operation (2 - 2), fixed
1: 1 operation (2 / 2)
4: 1 operation (2 + 2 or 2 * 2)
```

Now let's take `1`. The number of operations for new numbers will be the sum of the input numbers' number of operations plus 1. So, using `1`, we could

```
2 + 1 = 3 with 0 + 1 + 1 = 2 operations (2 + (2 / 2))
0 + 1 = 1 with 3 operations --> the existing number of operations for `0` is better, so we do not update
1 + 1 = 2 with 3 operations
2 - 1 = 1 with 2 operations
0 - 1 = -1 with 3 operations  *new*     
1 - 2 = -1 with 2 operations  *update*
1 - 0 = 1 with 3 operations
1 - 1 = 0 with 3 operations
2 * 1 = 2 with 2 operations
0 * 1 = 0 with 3 operations
1 * 1 = 1 with 3 operations    
2 / 1 = 2 with 2 operations
0 / 1 = 0 with 3 operations
1 / 2 = invalid if you only want to consider integers, use it otherwise
1 / 0 = invalid
1 / 1 = 1 with 3 operations
```

So, our list is now:

```
 2: 0 operations, fixed
 0: 1 operation (2 - 2), fixed
 1: 1 operation (2 / 2), fixed
 3: 2 operations (2 + 2/2)
 4: 1 operation (2 + 2 or 2 * 2)
-1: 2 operations (2/2 - 2)
```

Go on and take `4` and so on. Once you've reached your target number `x`, you are done in the smallest possible way.

In pseudo code:

```
L = create a new list with pairs of numbers and their number of operations
put (y, 0) into the list
while there are unfixed entries in the list:
    c = take the unfixed entry with the least number of operations
    fix c
    if c = x:
       finish
    for each available operation o:
        for each fixed number f in L:
            newNumber = o(c, f)
            operations = c.numberOfOperations + f.numberOfOperations + 1
            if newNumber not in L:
                add (newNumber, operations) to L
            else if operations < L[newNumber].numberOfOperations:
                update L[newNumber].numberOfOperations = operations

            repeat for o(f, c)
```

If you store the operation list with the numbers (or their predecessors), you can reconstruct the expression at the end.

Instead of using a simple list, a priority queue will make the retrieval of unfixed entries with the minimum number of operations fast.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code for this problem which I don't think is the fastest and the most optimal algorithm, but it should always find the best answer.
First, let's assume we don't have parentheses and solve the subproblem for finding the minimum number of operations to convert `a` to `n` with these operations `['+', '*', '/', '-']`. For solving this problem we use BFS. First we define an equation class:

```
class equation:
    def __init__(self, constant, level=0, equation_list=None):
        self.constant = constant
        if equation_list != None:
            self.equation_list = equation_list
        else:
            self.equation_list = [constant]
        self.level = level
        
    def possible_results(self):
        return recursive_possible_results(self.equation_list)

    def get_child(self, operation):
        child_equation_list = self.equation_list + [operation]
        child_equation_list += [self.constant]
        child_level =  self.level + 1
        return equation(self.constant, child_level, child_equation_list)
```

The constructor gets a constant which is the *constant* in our expressions (here is `a`) and a *level* which indicates the number of operations used in this equation, and an *equation_list* which is a list representation of equation expression. For the first node, ( *root* ) our level is 0, and our equation_list has only the constant.

Now let's calculate all possible ways to parentheses an equation. We use a recursive function which returns a list of all possible results and their expressions:

```
calculated_expr = {}

def is_operation(symbol):
    return (symbol in operations)

def recursive_possible_results(equation_list):
    results = []
    
    if len(equation_list) == 1:
        return [{'val': equation_list[0], 'expr': str(equation_list[0])}]
    
    key = ''
    for i in range(len(equation_list)):
        if is_operation(equation_list[i]):
            key += equation_list[i]
    
    if key in calculated_expr.keys():
        return calculated_expr[key]

    for i in range(len(equation_list)):
        current_symbol = equation_list[i]
        if is_operation(current_symbol):
            left_results = recursive_possible_results(equation_list[:i])
            right_results = recursive_possible_results(equation_list[i+1:])

            for left_res in left_results:
                for right_res in right_results:
                    try:
                        res_val = eval(str(left_res['val']) + current_symbol + str(right_res['val']))
                        res_expr = '(' + left_res['expr'] + ')' + current_symbol + '(' + right_res['expr'] + ')'
                        results.append({'val': res_val, 'expr': res_expr})
                    except ZeroDivisionError:
                        pass
    calculated_expr[key] = results
    return results
```

*(I think this is the part of the code that needs to be more optimized since we are calculating a bunch of equations more than once. Maybe a good dynamic programming algorithm ...)*

For Breadth-First-Search we don't need to explore the whole tree from the root. For example for converting 2 to 197, we need at least 7 operations since our biggest number with 6 operations is 128 and is still less than 197. So, we can search the tree from level 7. Here is a code to create our first level's nodes (equations):

```
import math
import itertools 

def create_first_level(n, constant):
    level_exprs = []

    level_number = int(math.log(n, constant)) - 1
    level_operations = list(itertools.product(operations, repeat=level_number))
    for opt_list in level_operations:
        equation_list = [constant]
        for opt in opt_list:
            equation_list.append(opt)
            equation_list.append(constant)
        level_exprs.append(equation(constant, level_number, equation_list))
    return level_exprs
```

In the end, we call our BFS and get the result:

```
def re_express(n, a):
    visit = set()

    queue = []
    # root = equation(a)
    # queue.append(root)
    # Skip levels
    queue = create_first_level(n, a)

    while queue:
        curr_node = queue.pop(0)

        for operation in operations:
            queue.append(curr_node.get_child(operation))
        
        possible_results = curr_node.possible_results()
        for pr in possible_results:
            if pr['val'] == n:
                print(pr['expr'])
                print('Number of operations: %d' % curr_node.level)
                queue = []
                break

        



re_express(9, 2)
```

Here is the output:

```
(((2)+(2))*(2))+((2)/(2))
Number of operations: 4
```

Comment: Using reverse polish notation instead of an ocean of parentheses might make the problem easier.

Comment: That's right. Thank you. But I still can't figure out how to calculate and iterate over all possible postfix notations?

Comment: @mirzanahal  Yes, some optimization required. Try `re_express(197, 2)`

Comment: >it should always find the best answer. Not always. `re_express(25, 4)` gives `(4)+((4)+(((4)*(4))+((4)/(4))))` with  5 operations while there exists a solution `(4 + 4/4) * (4 + 4/4)` with 3 operations.

Comment: @YuriGinsburg Isn’t / an operation? If it is your answer has 5 operations too. Also, thank you for the test (197, 2) I’ll check on that.

Comment: @YuriGinsburg Oh! I see. For computing `re_express(197, 2)` we need at least 7 operations (since `2^7 < 197` and it's the greatest number we can achieve at level 6). I think we can have a preprocess procedure to skip these 6 levels and start our BFS from level 7...

Comment: @mirzanahal Sorry about  number of  operations. My bad, But I was running `re_express(197, 2)` for 12+ hours on Intel I-7 3.0Ghz with no result. Does your algorithm works only for `n < 128`. I saw no restrictions in the code. It seems to me that complexity is this algorithm is something like `(n - a)!`

Comment: @YuriGinsburg I edit my answer with those skip levels but it's still slow and I couldn't get results, too. It's fast in creating the first layer but it's too slow on `recursive_possible_results`.

Comment: @YuriGinsburg I've been testing the algorithms, it seems that the time complexity is dependent on the level of the result. For example for `re_express(60, 2)` takes less than a second and the result is in level 6. However, for one number more, `re_express(61, 2)` takes about 1 minute and a couple of seconds and the result is in level 8. Again I did some more optimizations, in a dictionary save results from `recursive_possible_results` so it wouldn't compute repetitive results. Still, computations over level 8 become so exhaustive that I stuck at this level for more than 15 minutes.